# Under what conditions is $\det(\alpha A + B)=0$ true for a $\alpha \in \Bbb R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given two real matrices $A$ and $B$ where $A$ is symmetric ($A^T=A$), can one deduce some condition(s) under which

$$\det(\alpha A + B)=0$$

is satisfied only if $\alpha \in \Bbb R$? In my case, $ A$ and $ B$ are $8 \times 8$ matrices.

Comment: Have you attempted to find an answer on your own? If so, where is your working?

Comment: I have been trying numerical approach, but too many variables make it difficult to conclude anything useful. So I thought, maybe there is some smart analytic way of doing this--which I have no expertise of.

Comment: Are you only trying to find conditions that are sufficient for this to be true, or do you need conditions which are necessary for this to be true?

Comment: @Zilch perhaps you should change title to make clear that you want conditions *only* when $\alpha$ is real

Comment: @Maxwell, a sufficient condition would also work for me.

Comment: I think the a general condition is that $A$ and $B$ must share an eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_A$ and $\lambda_B$ then $\alpha = -\lambda_B/\lambda_A$. This reads close to something like a homogeneous Sylvester equation so simultaneous diagonalizability is important probably

Comment: @whpowell96, could you elaborate your comment in the form of an answer?

Comment: If you know that $A$ is invertible, then rewrite this as $\det(A^{-1}B+\alpha I) = 0$, so $-\alpha$ will be an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}B$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @whpowell96,

> If $A$ and $B$ share a common eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_A\neq 0$ and $\lambda_B\in\mathbb{R}$ respectively, then $\alpha=-\frac{\lambda_B}{\lambda_A}$
> is a real value such that $\det(\alpha A+B)=0$.

This is not hard to prove.
First, a real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable with real eigenvalues,
so $\lambda_A$ and hence $\alpha$ are real.
Also, if a matrix has a zero eigenvalue,
then it is not invertible and has zero determinant.
We need only show that $\alpha A+B$ has a zero eigenvalue.
Note that $(\alpha A+B)v=(\alpha\lambda_A+\lambda_B)v=0v$,
so we have shown $\det(\alpha A+B)=0$.

---

Note that such $\alpha$ may not always exist.
Consider
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\ 
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then $\det(\alpha A+B)=\alpha^2+1$,
so no real $\alpha$ vanishes the determinant.